# A better solution to make a separate instance of a nested dictionary?

Tags: python

I'm using a *parent* dict from which to generate a *child*, here's the problem :

```
child = parent
```

This obviously means editing the child will also edit the parent, they're just different names for the same object. **I want them to be separate objects**

```
child=parent.copy()
child=dict(parent)
```

Both of these solve the problem **only** for top level key:value pairs. Any value that's a nested dict is still shared between child and parent

```
child=json.loads(json.dumps(parent))
```

This is the only solution I've found that works but it feels so ***wrong*** ! Does anyone know a better/simpler way ?

Comment: `import copy; copy.deepcopy`?

Comment: deepcopy is what you need